# Как Android находит zImage?

Tags: android, boot

Вопрос теоретического характера. Как Android находит и, более того, загружает zImage и ramdisk.cpio.gz? Оба этих файла находятся в boot.img, который **НЕ** представляет собой файловую систему (он даже не монтируется). По идее, чтобы загрузить ядро, система должна смонтировать *rootfs* и найти там файлы загрузки (`C:\Boot` в Windows, `/boot` в Unix/Linux/macOS). Казалось бы - может дело в архитектуре ARM, но нет: `/boot` виден даже в Armbian и - какая неожиданность - в iPhone (https://miro.medium.com/max/1280/0*F8YaOt8iZza6NL9Z). Но как Android находит и исполняет boot.img? Мне интересен в первую очередь сам механизм, но и на код, например, того же **Fastboot**, я бы посмотрел.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В чипе есть загрузчик, который читает из флешки загрузчик fastboot, uboot или который там актуален, который лежит по фиксированному адресу. Этот загрузчик имеет свои настройки, читает их. В них записано в каком секторе лежит ядро. Загрузчик его копирует в оперативку вместе рамдиском полностью и стартует.